# Wistia resumable video uploads via API

Tags: api, video, upload, resume, wistia

I am looking for a way to resume a video upload once it is disrupted (due to a connection error or whatever other reason) using Wistia's upload API. I am using Wistia as a video host/provider and they seem to only offer such a feature using their own Uploader JavaScript plugin (I use blueimp's uploader). Has anyone managed something like that? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after contacting their support they told me that up to this date they do not support resumable video uploads. It is in their future plans though.